# problem with adding to a new table with PDO connection

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and I am trying to insert elements from a table to another using PDO connection. I have a table of products which I show on my product page and when I select one of them I would like the product id and the quantity to be added to the cart which has its own table. The problem I am having right now is that I cannot add anything to the cart table. Does anybody have any idea on how to solve this? Thanks.

products.php

```
<?php 
$pdo = new PDO(
  "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Shopping_cart;charset=utf8",
  "root",
  "root"
  );


    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM products");
    $statement->execute();

    $products = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    ?>

    <?php foreach ($products as $single_product) : ?>

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 mb-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
          <form action="index.php" method="POST">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="<?= $single_product['img']; ?>">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title" id="title_name"><?= $single_product['name']; ?></h4>
                <h5 name="price"><?= $single_product['price'] . ' kr'; ?></h5>
                <p class="card-text"><?= $single_product['descr']; ?></p>
              </div> 
              <div class="card-footer">
              <label for="amount">Choose Amount</label>
              <input type="text" name="quantity" id="amount">
              <input type="hidden" name="prod_id" value="<?= $single_product['product_id']; ?>">
              <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" class="removeOrBuy" value="Add To Cart">

              </div> 
              </form>
          </div><!--h-100-->
        </div><!--col-sm-12-->
```

addtocart.php

```
  <?php

  $pdo = new PDO(
  "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Shopping_cart;charset=utf8",
  "root",
  "root"
  );

       if(isset($_POST['add_to_cart'])) {
          $prod_id = $_POST['prod_id'];
          $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

           $statement = $pdo->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO cart (product_id, quantity)
            SELECT (product_id, quantity) FROM products"
            );
            $statement->execute(
             [
               ":quantity" => $quantity,
               "product_id" => $prod_id
             ]
            );
          }

         header('Location: index.php');   


        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your INSERT statement syntax is incorrect, use...

```
   $statement = $pdo->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO cart (product_id, quantity)
                   VALUES (:product_id, :quantity)"
        );
```

Also your `form` has...

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
```

which will not call the other script...

```
<form action="addtocart.php" method="POST">
```

Comment: That was my first attempt. But didn't work out. Then I have found the syntax I am using on this website dofactory.com/sql/insert-into

Comment: I've added a new bit, your form may have not been calling the add script.

Comment: Actually no error. But when I check on phpMyAdmin if my cart table have been populated I find that nothing has been added.